# Images in css animation not loading fully before being displayed in firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox, animation

I'm working on a website layout that uses css animation, animation delays and opacities for a fading image slideshow. Very similar to this [code](http://codepen.io/antoniskamamis/pen/hjBrE).

In IE and Chrome, the images appear in full and the animation works perfectly. In Firefox however, only part of each image is displayed as it cycles. This can be seen in the code.io link through Firefox or image link.
http://i60.tinypic.com/24yr536.png

It is as if the images are not completely downloaded before they are displayed.

I have tried this on two separate Win7 machines with Firefox 35 and a Win8.1 tablet with the same results. My internet connection is ADSL 2+ if it is to do with download speed.
I have already tried to use a dummy animation with a `animation-delay: 3s;` on the container function to give the img animation time to load but that didn't work.
Changing the image file size did help display more of the image but bits were still missing.
There doesn't appear to be anybody else with this issue through searches which makes me think it could just be a setting on my computers.

So far have managed to avoid using javascript in this page would prefer to keep it that way but if it is the only solution I would be happy to consider it.

Is there any way to make this slideshow appear properly in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is a difficult to replicate bug in Firefox 35.
I installed 36 beta and the rendering issue was resolved.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1122845